# Is this an example of a distributed database?

Tags: database, distributed

If a db "A" created at site alpha then also schema copied at site beta still data in both is same and must be in sync, is that a distributed database or would it be wrong?

If not, why is it not distributed? What does it need to be called distributed? Same schema different data? Or...?

Comment: Please provide a link to a definition of "Distributed Database" that you like.  There are several, which one do you prefer?

Comment: Perhaps you could you elaborate on the question - is this purely hypothetical, or do you have 2 DB's that you need to sync up..? Why 2 DB's in sync rather than 1 DB?

Comment: self learning, no reason currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. It is not a distributed DB, and it is not wrong. It is a copy of a database. The real question is how to keep them in sync.

Comment: What definition are you using?  Can you provide some details?

Comment: well go to wikipedia and distributed database....."A distributed database is a collection of

    multiple, logically interrelated databases

    distributed over a computer network.

Sometimes "distributed database system" is

used to refer jointly to the distributed

database and the distributed DBMS"

Comment: "..must be in sync" sounds like the DB's are not in sync but need to be? Hence it sounds like you have 2 disconnected DB's. But if they are connected & sync'd then yes, you have a Distributed Database.